# Can I get comments on posts in the community tab with the following request, just like comments on videos?

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I have a question.

1) Can I get comments on posts in the community tab with the following request, just like comments on videos?

`GET https: // www.googleapis.com / youtube / v3 / commentThreads`

2) Can it be put on hold with the following requests?

`POST https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/comments/setModerationStatus?moderationStatus=heldForReview`